# When may a body be removed from its resting place and buried elsewhere?

Tags: halacha, death, funeral-burial-levaya

In what instances may a body be removed from its resting place and be interred elsewhere?

Comment: YD 363. [15cha]

Comment: Do you have some reason to think such cases exist? Do yuo have some reason to think there is any limitation on such cases?

Comment: If the only way you get around the system's not allowing questions which duplicate the title is by using synonyms, then I think you're doing it wrong.

Comment: There was a case of this in my community a few years ago, where a family wanted to move someone to be with the rest of the family.  It was quite controversial.

Comment: See mishna Sanhedrin [6, 6](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37945&st=&pgnum=426&hilite=) about removing only after decomposition of the body.
See S YD 363 about removing to Erets Israel or to familial property

Answer (score 1):

Generally, a body may not be moved. However, see [this article](http://www.rabbinicalassembly.org/sites/default/files/public/halakhah/teshuvot/19912000/geller_exhuming.pdf) for details. Excerpted:

> The Talmud Yerushalmi permits the removal of remains, even from a
>   worthy to an unworthy place, that they may be buried with the
>   ancestors of the deceased
>
> In his code, Rabbi Joseph Karo adds other circumstances when
>   exhumation may be permitted or is required:
>
> A. It is a mitzvah for children to rebury a parent's body in Eretz
>   Yisrael, even if the parent expressed objection during his lifetime to
>   having his remains moved there.
>
> B. When a burial site is unprotected from robbers or natural forces,
>   it is permissible to remove bodies to locations that are not so
>   compromised.
>
> c. When a stipulation is made at the time of burial about the removal
>   of the body at a later date.
>
> D. When a body is buried in an available site, but without
>   authorization from its owner, the body may he moved.

Comment: A is not accurate. The case of when parents state otherwise is only discussed in later authorities (see Pitchei Teshuva)