# Is there a halachic objection to human composting?

Tags: halacha, death, funeral-burial-levaya

I just had a discussion with a friend about [this organization](http://www.urbandeathproject.org/#home), which proposes to inter human bodies in a giant composter (from which the family can retrieve the compost later) instead of burying them in individual graves. Would this be a kosher burial (or *could* it be kosher under the right circumstances)? If not, why not?

EDIT: It's been suggested that this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/593/cremations-for-jews). It's not. That question is about cremation. This one is not about cremation. They *are* both about the appropriate treatment of human corpses, but cremation and decomposition are completely different situations, and it doesn't make sense to generalize from one to the other. Thus it's not a duplicate, QED.

Comment: A very original question. I heard that in Chazal someone wanted to make a carpet with his father. So, i I remember, the conclusion was that there is a ban to make any use of the body after death. If I found it I will post an answer.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68859/1713

Comment: @kouty It's Mishna that they were Gozeir Tumah on human skin even after it is processed into leather to avoid people making carpets out of relatives.

Comment: @kouty What counts as use here? I mean, in a traditional cemetery the bodies decompose into the soil and nourish the grass & trees. How different would this be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cremations for Jews?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/593/cremations-for-jews)

Comment: @sabbahillel It's not possible to be a duplicate when the question doesn't mention cremation. Letting bodies rot naturally before moving the remains in order to save space is actually the traditional form of Jewish burial, unlike cremation.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45275/when-may-a-body-be-removed-from-its-resting-place-and-buried-elsewhere

Comment: Is it called Soylent Green?

Comment: I think composting has nothing to do with burying. The body is decomposed into the soil and the question is what to do with that soil. The composting itself is NOT the burial, as I understand it. https://www.wbur.org/hereandnow/2019/05/16/human-composting-washington

Comment: @DoubleAA I heard somebody (in Shu"A Hil. Kvurah) mentions the tradition of spilling hot lime on the body to speed the process of rotting to collect the bones later and rebury. However, the body was placed in a grave and this very process WAS the burial, while in composting the body is decomposed elsewhere and the remains are passed to the family to bury. Can you find the source of this tradition?

Answer (score 4):

Make fertilizer with a deceased body...

A quick outline of answer, or rather a strong intuition.
First: facultative references copied from massoret Hashass Chulin 122a (each page is for the Tosfot primarily)

[Chulin 122a](http://dtorah.com/otzar/shas_daf.php?ms=Chullin&df=122a)

> Mishnah:…if any of these skins was tanned or trampled upon as much as [was usual] for tanning, it becomes clean, excepting the skin of a man. R' johanan b. nuri says, the eight reptiles have [real] skins. Gemara Ulla said: According to the law of the Torah the skin of a man is clean, but for what reason did they say it was unclean? As a precautionary measure lest a man make rugs out of the skin of his father and mother.

[Zevachim 71b](http://dtorah.com/otzar/shas_daf.php?ms=Zevachim&df=71b)

[Nidah 55a](http://dtorah.com/otzar/shas_daf.php?ms=Nidah&df=55a)

[Baba-Kama 10a](http://dtorah.com/otzar/shas_daf.php?ms=Baba-Kama&df=10a)

[Arachin 4a](http://dtorah.com/otzar/shas_daf.php?ms=Arachin&df=4a)

[Sanhedrin 48a](http://dtorah.com/otzar/shas_daf.php?ms=Sanhedrin&df=48a)

> Rabeynu Tam explains that despite that a dead is banned from profit, Chachomim decreed an uncleaness because people are attentive to uncleannes more than that are attentive to ban

See Tosfot Sanhedrin 48A, the first of the page. 1) make profit from human body is banned 2) Chachomim made **a special effort** to reinforce the obedience 3) The concerning with the body of **deceased father** for the **riding** , **donkey** is pointed by the Gemara (Ula, Chulin 122A) this is a signpost. The concerning with bodies ... does that ring a bell? ... crematory oven. My quick hunch is that they want to deny the respect of mankind. The sages of the Talmud know how to teach through clear allusions (riding, donkey) what is hidden (consciously or **unconsciously**) beyond human behavior, **a desire to humiliate, to deny. (remember that when father and mother are alive, there is strong mitsva to honor and fear them)**.

Comment: Far be it from me to question Chazal, but why would they be worried that a man would make rugs out of the skins of his parents? That seems like a pretty unlikely scenario, to put it mildly.

Comment: @crmdgn I agree that this quite shocking. It's a powerful image. We are forced to make a pause for though.

Comment: That's not the point I'm making. The scenario in the mishna _would never actually happen_. So why is it a basis for halacha?

Comment: @crmdgn I am not going to pretend I know. Thats why I was talking about intuition. There is a tentation, there is a risk; I accept the idea. Chachomim prevented. More idea Chamor ~ Chomer. Parents are linked to Hashem, function of causality. Bits and pieces. no more.

Comment: Quelle tentation? Quelle risque?

Comment: @crmdgn Regardless of the language used I don't know more ;(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37928/discussion-between-kouty-and-crmdgn).

Answer (score 2):

The body must be buried without being cut up. Even an autopsy should be avoided if possible. Composting which is the treating of a body as if it is garbage to be disposed of is most similar to cremation.

If some of the limbs were severed and left unburied, the Mitzvah of burial is not fulfilled, as ruled in the Jerusalem Talmud, Tractate Nazir 33a.

For example [The Interment By Maurice Lamm](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/281565/jewish/The-Interment.htm)

> Jewish law is unequivocal in establishing absolutely, and
>   uncompromisingly, that the dead must be buried in the earth. Man's
>   body returns to the earth as it was.
>
> The blood and limbs of an individual are considered by Jewish law to
>   be part of the human being. As such, they require burial. If the
>   deceased was found with severed limbs, or with blood-stained clothes,
>   both the limbs and the clothes must be buried with him.
>
> If limbs were amputated during one's lifetime, they require burial in
>   the person's future gravesite. If he does not own a plot as yet, or if
>   he is squeamish in this regard, it should be buried in a separate
>   plot, preferably near the graves of members of his family. The limbs
>   are cleansed and placed in the earth. No observance of mourning is
>   necessary.
>
> **Donation of Limbs to Hospitals**
>
> Jewish law generally discourages contribution of one's limbs to
>   hospitals. If one has absolutely stipulated that a limb be donated for
>   medical research, the question of following his will depends on many
>   details, and requires rabbinic research. It is best, therefore, to
>   consult an expert on Jewish law. At any rate, even if it were
>   permitted, the limb would require burial when it is no longer in use
>   by the medical institution.

Comment: PTIJ are out of season i thought... the only similarity composting shares with cremation it also shares with burial (landfills are indeed where most of our garbage goes)

Comment: In this scenario the body is not treated as garbage, but buried as you describe; the only difference is that in this case the earth the body is buried in is inside a giant composting tower. That being case, the body is "returning to the earth," as it would otherwise.