# Human Composting - Implications for Kohanim

Tags: death, kohen-priest, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, funeral-burial-levaya, composting

In recent news, Washington State, [has becomes the first state ever to allow human composting](https://www.foxnews.com/politics/washington-becomes-first-state-ever-to-allow-human-composting).

The question has already been raised in this forum:  "[Is there a halachic objection to human composting?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69987/is-there-a-halachic-objection-to-human-composting)"

The present question is, does such a law have halachic ramifications for Kohanim? If yes, what are they?

If the remaining soil is given to the family, and they spread it around town, in all the deceased's favorite haunts, like parks and hiking trails, does that pose a problem for Kohanim?

If they spread the soil in their backyard garden, and raise vegetables from him/her, does that pose a problem for Kohanim?

Answer (score 4):

Hilchot Tumat Met 3:6 explains that a body which is intentionally ground into dust does not transmit tumah.